# Ignore xml element while marshalling and include xml element while unmarsalling by using XmlTransient annotation

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal an XML into an object that I expect should have a certain field. However, I do not want to marshal that object into an XML that contains it. What I like would be similar to this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
public class User {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.........", required = false)
    private String name;

}
```

While marshalling , am getting below xml,

Current xml output file looks like:

```
<User xmlns:ns5="http://www......." />
```

But I don't want this namespace in output file,
Expected looks like below xml output file,

```
<User />
```

I tried to use @XmlTransient annotation,

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
public class User {

    @XmlTransient
    private String name;

}
```

Worked successfully while marshalling and got exception while unmarshalling

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: No descriptor found while unmarshalling element mapped to user name
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you would not want to get the `namespaces` in your XML. Based on my understanding providing the answer here. Hope it helps or at least guides you in the right direction.

I have done something like this:

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
public class User {

    @XmlTransient
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.google/test.com", required = false)
    private String name;

    private String name1;

    public void beforeMarshal(Marshaller m) {
        //Executed after reading the data but before marshalling to XML. Here you can perform whatever you would like.
        name1 = name;
        name = null;
    }

    public void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller m, Object parent) {
        //Executed after Unmarshalling the data. Here you can perform whatever you would like.
    }

}
```

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Batman");

        final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);

        final Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(user, System.out);
    }
}
```

This would result in following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<User>
   <name1>Batman</name1>
</User>
```

You can perform accordingly whatever you need within the `beforeMarshal` and `afterMarshal` if required.